# output different extension other than .php in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Refer to this article [http://filext.com/faq/fake_file_extensions.php][1]. I have a website which runs in apache (PHP and mysql). I want to display url with `.fake` extension instead of `.php` . I want apache to process all the requests with `.fake` extension as it do with `.php`. Is it possible by write something into `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What did you try and what do you exactly want ? There's 2 solutions: first is to have virtual extensions (eg, file.xxx rewritten to file.php where php is the real extension) or you can define all xxx files extension to be interpreted as something (eg, php files)

Comment: Why would you want to ever change the extension like that?

Comment: This will **not** make your site more secure in the slightest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Rewrite URL's to their php counter-part. The files on the server end with .php. You use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the urls

   ```
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.fake$ $1.php [L]
   ```
2. Add a php handler for the fake extension. The files reside with a .fake extension on your server and you tell apache to use the php application to process these files. You send them with the text/html mime type back to the client.

   ```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .fake
   AddType text/html .fake
   ```

There is no real reason to do the second approach, unless you want to confuse fellow developers.